# Get list of members and their permissions in azure devops project

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops

I want to extract the groups/members/emails and their roles/permissions of a project in azure devops
so i've tried the [azure-devops](https://pypi.org/project/azure-devops/) python lib  and this is the code:

```
old_merge_environment_settings = requests.Session.merge_environment_settings

@contextlib.contextmanager
def no_ssl_verification():
    opened_adapters = set()

    def merge_environment_settings(self, url, proxies, stream, verify, cert):
        # Verification happens only once per connection so we need to close
        # all the opened adapters once we're done. Otherwise, the effects of
        # verify=False persist beyond the end of this context manager.
        opened_adapters.add(self.get_adapter(url))

        settings = old_merge_environment_settings(self, url, proxies, stream, verify, cert)
        settings['verify'] = False

        return settings

    requests.Session.merge_environment_settings = merge_environment_settings

    try:
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter('ignore', InsecureRequestWarning)
            yield
    finally:
        requests.Session.merge_environment_settings = old_merge_environment_settings

        for adapter in opened_adapters:
            try:
                adapter.close()
            except:
                pass


def get_project_id_from_name(connection, project_name="project_name"):
    core_client = connection.clients_v6_0.get_core_client()
    get_projects_response = core_client.get_projects()
    while get_projects_response is not None:
        for project in get_projects_response:
            if project.name.lower() == project_name.lower():
                return project.id
    return None


def get_team_prop_from_project(connection, project_id):
    core_client = connection.clients_v6_0.get_core_client()
    team_id = core_client.get_teams(project_id)[0].id
    get_team_members_response = core_client.get_team_members_with_extended_properties(project_id=project_id, team_id=team_id)
    return get_team_members_response


def get_ad_members():
    from azure.devops.connection import Connection
    from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication

    from azure.devops.v6_0.security.security_client import SecurityClient
    from azure.devops.client import Client

    with no_ssl_verification():
        personal_access_token = "***********************************"
        organization_url = 'https://azuredevops.**.*****.****/organazation'

        # Create a connection to the org
        credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
        connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

        project_id = get_project_id_from_name(connection, project_name="project_name")
        team_prop = get_team_prop_from_project(connection, project_id)

        return team_prop
```

but this is the out put of team_prop:

[image]

i've tried this also in get_ad_members() just before returning team_prop value :

`connection.clients_v6_0.get_graph_client().list_groups()`

but i got this error:

`The requested resource requires user authentication: https://azuredevops.**.*****.****/_apis

group/members/emails and their roles/permissions

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I want to extract the groups/members/emails and their roles/permissions of a project in azure devops based on this library : https://pypi.org/project/azure-devops/
this is the git repo of the lib: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api